# Rust Polars literal out of range

Tags: rust, rust-polars

The rust documentation provides the following example for numeric operations:

```
let df_numerical = df
    .clone()
    .lazy()
    .select([
        (col("nrs") + lit(5)).alias("nrs + 5"),
        (col("nrs") - lit(5)).alias("nrs - 5"),
        (col("nrs") * col("random")).alias("nrs * random"),
        (col("nrs") / col("random")).alias("nrs / random"),
    ])
    .collect()?;
println!("{}", &df_numerical);
```

I cannot get this to work for my use case.

I'm attempting to use the with_columns method to add a new column that converts a column called bytes to a column called tib:

```
df
.clone()
.lazy()
.with_columns([
    // convert bytes to tib
    (col("bytes")
        / lit(1099511627776)).alias("tib"),
])
.collect()
.unwrap();
```

I receive the error:

```
error: literal out of range for `i32`
   --> foo/src/main.rs:131:27
    |
131 |                     / lit(1099511627776)).alias("tib"),
    |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |
    = note: the literal `1099511627776` does not fit into the type `i32` whose range is `-2147483648..=2147483647`
    = help: consider using the type `i64` instead
    = note: `#[deny(overflowing_literals)]` on by default
```

How do I ensure that `lit` is of the type i64?

I've also tried this:

```
df
.clone()
.lazy()
.with_columns([
    // convert bytes to tib
    (col("bytes")
        / lit(i64::from(1099511627776))).alias("tib"),
])
.collect()
.unwrap();
```

Answer (score 1):

Required the `i64` suffix on the value.

```
df
.clone()
.lazy()
.with_columns([
    // convert bytes to tib
    (col("bytes")
        / lit(1099511627776i64).alias("tib"),
])
.collect()
.unwrap();
```